# How to access the removed header area in this drawer template in Material UI (MUI)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, header, grid, jsx

I'm currently exploring MUI, thus I used a drawer template from MUI and wanted to customize it a bit. I removed the header part of the template and may want to access the available space above by moving the text up until the available area but I'm having a difficulty on which I should tweak the code, especially in terms of grids or containers.

WITH HEADER (blue bar):

[image: WITH HEADER (blue bar)]

WITHOUT HEADER:
[image: WITHOUT HEADER]

ACCESS THIS AREA:
[image: ACCESS THIS AREA]

Source code(jsx file):

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

const drawerWidth = 240;

export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Permanent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>                  --- removed HEADER*/}    
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: "background.default", p: 3 }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
          integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate
          eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo
          quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat
          vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
          lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
          elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse
          sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat
          mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis
          risus sed vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas
          purus viverra accumsan in. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non
          tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique
          sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis
          eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla
          posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Your responses would help me a lot in terms of proper arrangement and accessing spaces. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is a `<Toolbar/>` component inside your `<main>` element.
That is causing the blank area in top of your page. You can easily remove it.

And by the way there is another `<Toolbar/>` just like the previous one inside your `<Drawer>` component that caused the blank area in the top of the drawer (top left side of the page).
You can delete that too.

Final code:

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Permanent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>                  --- removed HEADER*/}    
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        {/* <Toolbar /> */}
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: "background.default", p: 3 }}
      >
        {/* <Toolbar /> */}
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Definitely worked, the other toolbars really caused the inaccessible areas indeed. Anyways, thank you very much for pointing this out and tweaking the code also. MUI's really interesting!